# Problems when unloading data from local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

When I unload or send data from/to local storage, the order gets messed up. So how can I make sure the order stays when the data is uploaded to local storage?

[image]

```
    <div class="list" id="listSection">
        <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
            <li>four</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

```
function updateStorage() {
    let list_Sections = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    let i = 0;
    list_Sections.forEach((list) => {
        const table = {
            tagName: list.tagName,
            info: list.innerHTML,
        };
        i++;    
        localStorage.setItem(i, JSON.stringify(table));
    });
}
```

Any questions regarding for more information, please ask.

Thanks for the Help!

Comment: They aren't messed up. They are completely different key value pairs being stored so there technically is no order.

Comment: There's no order to localStorage. If you want to store ordered data, make it an array.

Comment: Object properties and values are not stored in a specific order.

Comment: make an array and sort it `array.sort();` then store in localstorage

Comment: No, @CodeBug, you shouldn't have to `.sort`, if you push in the order you want.... just `localStorage.someProperty = JSON.stringify(array);`.

Comment: @StackSlave, it works, but how do I unload the storage, when I try to parse the object, and try to get the ".info", it says undefined

Comment: nevermind, got it working, thanks for the help